# How to set up a specific frequency for letters to appear in an array

Tags: c, arrays

**This is for Homework**

So i'm making a game of scrabble as a project for school. In a game of scrabble each letter has a certain amount of times it can possibly appear. Ex: K can appear once , Z can appear twice, E can appear 12 times ect. So one way I thought of is just two make a huge array that has every possible letter in one array. So following the example I provided it would look like this:

```
 const char arr[] = {'K' , 'Z' , 'E' , 'E' , 'E',  'E'.....};
```

and it would eventually be an array with about 96 elements.

Rather I was wondering if there was a way to set up two arrays one with all 26 letters of the alphabet and another array with frequencies for every letter. This is what I have so far

```
 const char let[] = 
{'K' , 'J' , 'X' , 'Q' , 'Z' , 'B' , 'C' , 'M' , 'P' , 'F' , 'H' , 'V' , 'W' , 'Y' , 'G' , 'L' , 'S' , 'U' , 'D' , 'N' , 'R' , 'T' , 'O' , 'A' , 'I' , 'E'};

const int freq[] = 
{ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 6 , 6 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 9 , 12 };
```

I organized it so each element in both arrays can be correlated to each other. So K can show up once, J can show up once ect.

My question is how do I make it so my frequency array has an effect on my letter array kind of like a multiplier. If my question is unclear, please let me know in the comments but other than that I would appreciate any help.

Note: The letters would have to randomized eventually, I know how to do that so thats why I have them set as constants.

Comment: you mean you want to randomly select letters, but the selections should be weighted so some are more likely to be selected than others?

Comment: @yano correct but when I give the user the "hand of letters" there is a possibility of a letter like H which can show up a total of 4 times, to show up more than once

Comment: your first approach makes sense to me. Then you can just `rand() % 96` and the frequency distribution should be baked in. I'm sure there are different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I make it so my frequency array has an effect on my letter array kind of like a multiplier

From `freq[]`, count up the sum of frequencies --> `N`.

Form array `arr[N]`.

Populate it

```
 unsigned arr_index = 0;
 for (i=0; i<26; i++) {
   for (f=0; f<freq[i]; f++) {
     arr[arr_index++] = let[i];
   }
 }
```

[Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) `arr[N]`

Comment: is the arr_index the letter array?

Comment: @chrisHG `arr_index` is  the index of the 96 (or whatever) scrabble letters

Comment: so I think I know what you're saying but how exactly would this make it so a letter can show up multiple times when the user is given their letters?

Comment: @chrisHG "This is for Homework" + "how exactly would this make ..." ≠ good learning experience.  Your call.

Comment: I got you, I played around with the program and got it. Thanks for the help!